# Where do I ask questions about the Windows OS?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Where do I ask questions about the Windows operating systems? Be it Win 8, 7 or XP.

The questions that I want to ask *may not* be strictly related to a problem I am facing, but related to files and features of the OS itself or asking just because of my curiosity. For example, I want to know the purpose of the file "Bootvid.dll" in a Win 8 OS.  Or, for example, I want to what "hal.dll" is.

Are these questions appropriate for Stack Overflow or Super User? If not, please recommend some SE sites in which I can post such questions, because I am interested in getting into the guts of the Windows OS. Open to all suggestions.

Comment: WHY do you want to know? Is this a question that came up while you were programming? Or being super userish? Answer that & you'll have your answer...

Comment: Came up while getting some BSOD due to antivirus conflicts.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If the questions are not specifically related to programming, then I would recommend asking the question on [Super User](https://superuser.com/). There you can ask questions about different files in Windows and what they do, as well as errors or problems that you have while using the Windows operating system. If you are new to Super User you can get a tour of the website [HERE](https://superuser.com/about), which introduces you to how Super User works. However, your question cannot be about:

> "Electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except
>   insofar as they interface with your computer"

Comment: Strange that "Super User" is the Windows site, since "super user", or "su", is a Linux tool.

Comment: @user153505 `su` stands for "substitute user," not "super user." It's just many people only ever use it to become the super user ;)

Comment: @Chris I think it may mean "switch user" https://linuxize.com/post/su-command-in-linux/

Comment: The man page says "substitute user".